# Universal pathing in a React app with multiple workspaces - how to do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So I've got a monorepo I am trying to use based on this one:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/tree/master/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase-typescript

This repo has 4 separate places where there is a package.json (and theoretically a tsconfig.json) - the app is partially TypeScript and partially Javascript (re-writing it gradually in TypeScript as time goes along)

Basically the directory structure looks like this:

```
/ - root directory
/apps/expo - expo-related packages, configurations, functions, etc
/apps/next - next-related packages, configuration, functions, etc
/packages/app/ - general business logic, code, pages, etc
```

No matter what I am trying to do or where I am trying to setup the routing, it isn't working.

Inside my tsconfig.json in my root folder, I have this (I have also tried putting it in the individual tsconfig.json files of the individual folders):

```
"paths": {
  "app/*": ["./packages/app/*"],
  "components/*": ["./packages/app/components"],
  "config/*": ["./packages/app/config"],
  "controllers/*": ["./packages/app/controllers"],
  "pages/*": ["./packages/app/pages"],
  "reducers/*": ["./packages/app/redux"],
  "resources/*": ["./packages/app/resources"],
  "revenuecat/*": ["./packages/app/revenuecat"],
  "routing/*": ["./packages/app/routing"],
  "utils/*": ["./packages/app/utils"],
  "interfaces/*": ["./packages/app/interfaces"],
  "root/*": ["./*"]
}
```

But none of these paths are recognized in my Next app.

I've tried putting in the babel.config.js of the Expo folder inside my plugins:

```
  [
    'module-resolver',
    {
      root: '../../packages',
      alias: {
        app: '../../packages/app',
        components: '../../packages/app/components',
        config: '../../packages/app/config',
        controllers: '../../packages/app/controllers',
        pages: '../../packages/app/pages',
        reducers: '../../packages/app/redux',
        resources: '../../packages/app/resources',
        revenuecat: '../../packages/app/revenuecat',
        routing: '../../packages/app/routing',
        utils: '../../packages/app/utils',
        interfaces: '../../packages/app/interfaces',
      },
    },
  ]
```

I've tried putting them in the .babelrc of the Next folder, also in my plugins:

```
[
  "module-resolver",
  {
    "root": "../../packages",
    "alias": {
      "app/*": "../../packages/app",
      "components": "../../packages/app/components",
      "config": "../../packages/app/config",
      "controllers": "../../packages/app/controllers",
      "pages": "../../packages/app/pages",
      "reducers": "../../packages/app/redux",
      "resources": "../../packages/app/resources",
      "revenuecat": "../../packages/app/revenuecat",
      "routing": "../../packages/app/routing",
      "utils": "../../packages/app/utils",
      "interfaces": "../../packages/app/interfaces"
    }
  }
]
```

The code I am trying to run is my _app.js which calls my Footer file in my /packages/app/components/main folder. The _app.js works fine and it gets to my Footer.web.js file, but then I get:

```
error - ../../packages/app/components/main/Footer.web.js:4:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'components/main/AppButtons'
  2 | import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';
  3 | import moment from 'moment';
> 4 | import AppButtonGroup from 'components/main/AppButtons';
  5 | import {
  6 |   Row,
  7 |   Column,
```

Now Appbuttons.tsx is in the same folder as Footer.web.js

My guess is that I need another .babelrc file for my /packages/app folder? Or is it another error?

My workspaces are set like this in my root package.json:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
```

What is causing this to not work? Why is my pathing not working in my /packages/app folder?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an MRE?

Comment: Why aren't you basing your project off of the typescript example? That is: [`GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase-typescript`](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/tree/master/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase-typescript). It looks like they might have solved your problem?

Comment: @webelo That is what I'm using, but I am trying to add universal importing to this starter

Comment: @StevenMatthews ok - I just wrote that because your link pointed to the non-ts version.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, yeah it should be the TS one, I'll update it

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

1. Add your path alias into the workspace root `tsconfig.json`, also add `"baseURL": "./"`.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
+    "baseUrl": "./",
     "strictNullChecks": true,
     "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
     "paths": {
       "app/*": ["./packages/app/*"],
+      "components/*": ["./packages/app/components/*"],
+      "config/*": ["./packages/app/config"],
       // ...
```

2. Config for `next`, install [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin), go to `apps/next/next.config.js` and apply this plugin:

```
const path = require('node:path');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
// ...

module.exports = withNativebase({
  // ...

  nextConfig: {
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      // ...

      config.resolve.plugins = [
        ...config.resolve.plugins,
        new TsconfigPathsPlugin({
          // Use the root `tsconfig.json`!
          configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json'),
        }),
      ]

      return config
    },
```

3. Config for `expo`, go to `apps/expo/babel.config.js`:

```
const path = require('node:path');

// ...

    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          root: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../'),
          alias: {
            app: './packages/app',
            components: './packages/app/components',
            // ...
          },
        },
      ]
    ]
```

### Explanation

First of all, let's me spit it out, I personally would've just use `"app/components/*"` as alias, so to avoid this config madness. But since you asked, here's the answer. See above for the solution, and below is some nerdy explanation on technical details. Skip if you don't care.

#### Truth of the `app/*` pseudo-alias

Without above config, only `app/*` alias works. But the reason's kinda special: this is NOT a real (in bundle tool's term) alias. It's in fact a real filesystem symlink `<root>/node_modules/app -> <root>/packages/app`.

This symlink is created by yarn/npm's workspace mechanism. Because it lives in `<root>/node_modules`, the alias-ish `app/*` path is actually resolved as if it's a real npm package.

#### One does not simply use alias

Now if you want to add your own real alias, you'll have to wrestle with build tools.

The template you use has two tooling setup: `next` for web, `expo` for native. You need to address them separately.

In this case, `tsconfig.json` -> `compilerOptions.paths` is mainly for IDE hint (e.g. vscode jump to definition). By default it's not used by either tools. So you still need to manually config alias via plugins like I've shown in solution section.

So yeah, 3 configs for 3 tools, madness.

#### Revisit pseudo-alias

Another solution is to leverage the workspace mechanism to create pseudo-alias, like in the case of `app/*`. For example, if you want `components/*` as "alias". You need to:

1. create `<root>/packages/components/package.json` and give it a `"name": "components"`.

> A lil twist: if you use `"name": "duck"` for whatever reason, your pseudo-alias will become `duck/*`, i.e., folder name does NOT matter. Only package name matters.

2. `cd` back to project root dir, and simply run `yarn`, you should now see a symlink at `<root>/node_modules/components`.
3. (optional step) You are *supposed* to add into `"dependencies": { "components": "*" }` in other workspace package's `package.json` (e.g., `apps/next/package.json`) if you want to use this `components/*` "alias", because it's in fact is another package named `"components"` that you depend on. It's a good practice to add dep package into `"dependencies"` field.

Quite laborious too, I know. But still an option.

Comment: Which tsconfig.json would I be putting this in? There is a generated tsconfig.json in the root, /apps/expo and /apps/next

Comment: @StevenMatthews The workspace root `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 1):

1. This does not answer your question, because you do not use webpack, but you can try this tool. The code will look like below.
2. Try to start your paths from "@".
3. Try to move your config into the root folder.

```
const {resolve} = require("path");
const TsConfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");
// ...

module.exports = {
    entry: "./packages/app/index.tsx",
    target: "web",
    output: {
        path: resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        publicPath: "/",
        chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js"
    },
    // ...
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        plugins: [new TsConfigPathsPlugin()],
        alias: {
            "@": resolve(__dirname, "packages/app"),
            "@components": resolve(__dirname, "packages/app/components"),
            "@config": resolve(__dirname, "packages/app/config"),
            "@pages": resolve(__dirname, "packages/app/pages"),
            // ...
        }
    },
    // ...
};
```

---

tsconfig will look like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": "./packages/app",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@components": ["./components"],

      "@config/*": ["./config/*"],
      "@config": ["./config"],

      "@pages/*": ["./pages/*"],
      "@pages": ["./pages"],

      // ...

      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "packages/app"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Next, I believe, does use webpack, just not a webpack *file*. Webpack is part of the webpack property that is part of next.config.js

Answer (score 1):

I would do something basic which might not work for your use case,

I'd use [`npm install <folder>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install?v=true#:%7E:text=npm%20install%20%3Cfolder%3E)

Since these dirs are npm packages,

```
/ - root directory
/apps/expo - expo-related packages, configurations, functions, etc
/apps/next - next-related packages, configuration, functions, etc
/packages/app/ - general business logic, code, pages, etc
```

If I wanted to access `/packages/app/` in `apps/next` dir, I'd do,

```bash
cd apps/next
npm install ../../packages/app --install-links
```

Assuming the `name` of package `packages/app` (in `package.json`) is `my-app-packages` I'd just use those like so,

```
import Routing from "my-app-packages/routing";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you accidentally added `/*` to the end of all path like `app/*`. Try changing your `paths` in **tsconfig.json** like below

```
"paths": {
  "app/*": ["./packages/app/*"],
  "components": ["./packages/app/components"],
  "config": ["./packages/app/config"],
  "controllers": ["./packages/app/controllers"],
  "pages": ["./packages/app/pages"],
  "reducers": ["./packages/app/redux"],
  "resources": ["./packages/app/resources"],
  "revenuecat": ["./packages/app/revenuecat"],
  "routing": ["./packages/app/routing"],
  "utils": ["./packages/app/utils"],
  "interfaces": ["./packages/app/interfaces"],
  "root": ["./*"]
}
```